# is there a way to stop a timer on visual studios at a certain point instead of it keep going

Tags: c#, timer, visual-studio-2013

basically I mean I want a picture to move when I press a button and the picture to sop moving at a certain point on the form application, not cancel it the picture to move then just stop with the application still running. on Microsoft visual studios c# windows form application

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;


        }
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Left += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `timer1.Stop()` to stop the timer.

You need to set the `Interval` property of the `timer` to `raise` the `TickEvent` once after that `Interval` is `Elapsed`.

In `TickEvent` you can `Stop` the `Timer` or do whatever you want to do.

Try This :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer1.Interval=5000;//to raise tick event for 5 sec's
timer1.Start();
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
}

protected void timer1_Tick(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{    
//Stop the timer here
timer1.Stop();    
}
```

Comment: good but is their away to put of the timer1.stop(); for a few seconds more